# Suppress Tap Gesture when user clicks on HTML button on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I have a view. Over this view i have placed a UIWebView.
Size of UIWebView is exactly same as that of the view.

On the view i have applied TapGesture. Whenever user taps on the web view my tap gesture method gets called which is fine as per my expectations.

Now issue arises when i load an HTML file with some buttons on it. These Buttons are associated with Javascript methods.

If i click on any button in html the javascript method gets called [Perfect] but i want to suppress the Native Tap gesture method on this case.

Can anybody suggest me what should i do to suppress tap gesture method.

I only want to suppress tap gesture method when user clicks on any HTML button that is already associated with some other method.

Waiting for help :)

Tap Gesture Code

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
        if (touch.tapCount ==1 && self.view.superview != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"tag  :: %ld",(long)touch.view.tag);
            NSLog(@"name :: %@",touch.view);
    BOOL isYesNo=NO;
              if(touch.view.tag!=100)// ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
                {
                    // we did not touched our UIWebView
         isYesNo=NO;

                }
                else
                {
                    // we touched our UIWebView
                    isYesNo=YES; 
                }
        }
        return isYesNo;
    }
```

TAG value is always returned as ZERO